# Image brightness and contrast adjustment on stereo image pairs

Tags: image-processing

I have a pair of stereo images captured with two different cameras.
They differ in brightness and contrast as they were not captured with global shutter cameras.
I need to apply semi global matching algorithm to obtain depth on them. This will lead to bad results if applied directly.

Any suggestions to equalize both the images to obtain good results?

Comment: Why not just calibrate them? Give them both the same lighting conditions/objects and measure the blacks/whites, and determine what contrast/brightness values normalize.

Comment: They both have been calibrated but they have different brightness and contrast.

Comment: Can you show some samples? By calibrate, I mean measure their responses to the same light intensities, and do a simple brightness/contrast fit.

Comment: Right: https://pasteboard.co/HsinfcL.png
Left :https://pasteboard.co/HsintML.png

Comment: You appear to have uploaded the same image twice.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! 
Right:https://pasteboard.co/HszotJl.png
Left: pasteboard.co/HsinfcL.png

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution can be:

- Find the histogram of the image that has good contrast and
  brightness.
- Use histogram matching to make the histogram of other
  image same.